# What is the basic structure of the proof?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, proof-writing

[image]

What is the basic structure of the proof?

I think it should be one of contrapositive or contradiction.

Comment: This is an example of proof by contradiction, can you see why?

Comment: Because we are assuming there are finitely many primes and we end up with a contradiction.

Comment: Exactly! You are correct :)

Comment: I don't think the argument is quite correct as it stands. Suppose one is so short-sighted not to see any prime beyond $2$, that is $r = 1$, and $p_1 = 2$. Then $N - 1 = 1$, which has no prime factor, so no contradiction here. It is much better to take $N + 1$ instead of $N - 1$.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti It is a somewhat sloppily written proof.

Comment: Or assume $r \ge 2$.

Answer (score 0):

This is a proof by contradiction; given a statement (there are infinitely many primes), we assume the opposite (there are finitely many primes), then derive a contradiction (some prime $p_i$ divides 1). As for the other methods:

- Proof contrapositive presumably refers to proving the implication $p \implies q$ by proving the logical contrapositive, $\lnot q \implies \lnot p$.
- Proof converse isn't an actual proof technique, as far as I'm aware. The converse of an implication $p \implies q$ is $q \implies p$, but these two statements are **not** logically equivalent.
- Proof by induction proves a statement $P(k)$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$ with $k$ larger than some minimum element $m$, usually $0$ or $1$. We prove a base case $P(m)$, then prove the implication $P(k) \implies P(k + 1)$.